# how to make geojson format in java

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, geojson

I have a question, how would this format in java with hibernate and mysql?

It could be a pojo for do this format something less complicated

```
 {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: [{
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [-77.032, 38.913]
        },
        properties: {
          title: 'Mapbox',
          description: 'Washington, D.C.'
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [-122.414, 37.776]
        },
        properties: {
          title: 'Mapbox',
          description: 'San Francisco, California'
        }
      }]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use geojson-Jackson, an extension of Jackson tool.

> A small package of all GeoJson POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects) for serializing and deserializing of objects via JSON Jackson Parser.

**Usage**

> If you know what kind of object you expect from a GeoJson file you can directly read it like this:

```
FeatureCollection featureCollection = 
new ObjectMapper().readValue(inputStream, FeatureCollection.class);
```

Please refer to the doc [geojson-jackson](https://github.com/opendatalab-de/geojson-jackson).

If you're looking for save the structure in your DB, maybe you should try one spatial column.
Check [Spatial types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-type-overview.html) and [geojson functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-geojson-functions.html).